# IBM MobileFirst Certificate Pinning

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, certificate-pinning

I want to use certificate pinning in my iOS IBM MobileFirst project.Can i place my certificate inside Mobile First Development kit. If yes then, how can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote "development kit" I assume you are referring to MobileFirst Foundation v8.0. The devkit uses the WebSphere Liberty profile application center. As mentioned [in the Certificate Pinning documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/certificate-pinning/#certificate-setup you should follow the Liberty documentatioh on where to place SSL certificates.

This is the doc you should follow: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.common.doc/topics/admin_mg_certs_waslib.html

It mentions where to place the certificate and what to update with the server.xml. All said locations are where you installed the devkit, as [that's where the Liberty server is](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/setting-up-your-development-environment/mobilefirst-development-environment/#mobilefirst-foundation-components).